# How to make ARRAY field with foreign key constraint in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

How to make column with ARRAY(Integer) type, where each integer is primary key from some other table? If it's impossible, how to achieve similar table relationships with other method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of PostgreSQL 9.3, this is not implemented, see
http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-9-3-development-array-element-foreign-keys/
One should turn array into other table.

Comment: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68275664/12263918 )  **_Using PostgreSQL array to store many-to-many relationship_**