# Create Column with Array of Model Class type in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, model, fastapi

I'm trying to create an Order model using SQLAlchemy with a Column having an Array of ProductItem Class defined, but it is throwing an exception
Both the classes are defined in the same file

**models.py**

```
# Product Item Class
class ProductItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product_items'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    productName = Column(String,index=True,nullable=False)
    productBrand = Column(String, nullable=False)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<ProductList(productName = '%s', productCategoryName = '%s')>" % (
            self.productName,
            self.productCategoryName
        )

#Order Class
class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    id= Column(Integer, index=True, primary_key=True)
    dateCreated = Column(DateTime,nullable=False)
    dateDelivered = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    orderItem = Column(ARRAY(ProductItem), nullable=False)  # This Column
    orderStatus = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

**Exception:**

```
>alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Initial db with order"
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'orders'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_orders_businessId' on '['businessId']'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_orders_customerId' on '['customerId']'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_orders_id' on '['id']'
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'product_categories_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'product_categories(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'business_billing_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'business_billing(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'business_timings_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'business_timings(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'product_items_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'product_items(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'inventory_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'inventory(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
Generating D:\app Backend\db-migration\versions\ceff7117b4cb_initial_db_without_order.py ...  done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mahesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\mahesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\app Backend\env\Scripts\alembic.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 559, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 553, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 530, in run_cmd
    fn(
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 219, in revision
    scripts = [script for script in revision_context.generate_scripts()]
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 219, in <listcomp>
    scripts = [script for script in revision_context.generate_scripts()]
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\autogenerate\api.py", line 533, in generate_scripts
    yield self._to_script(generated_revision)
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\autogenerate\api.py", line 449, in _to_script
    return self.script_directory.generate_revision(
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 658, in generate_revision
    script = Script._from_path(self, path)
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 851, in _from_path
    return cls._from_filename(scriptdir, dir_, filename)
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 904, in _from_filename
    module = util.load_python_file(dir_, filename)
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 97, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "d:\app backend\env\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\compat.py", line 182, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 786, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 923, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 853, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\App Backend\db-migration\versions\ceff7117b4cb_initial_db_without_order.py", line 25
    sa.Column('orderItem', sa.ARRAY(app.models.<app.models.ProductItem object at 0x00000256DF9ED100>), nullable=False),
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Searched a lot but couldn't find any docs describing custom types for the array. I need a way to store an array of ProductItem class in Order Class. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PostgreSQL:  documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html):

> PostgreSQL allows columns of a table to be defined as variable-length multidimensional arrays. Arrays of any **built-in or user-defined base type, enum type, composite type, range type, or domain** can be created.

Hence, you will not be able to create an `ARRAY` column of just any Python class, unless you create a corresponding *user-defined* type in the database, which is most likely against the reason of how one should use SQLAlchemy.

What you need is a way to create a [Many To Many](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) relationship which requires an association table.

---

See also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40104800/99594), a similar question although it focused on enforcing `ForeignKey` constraint from the `ARRAY` datatype.