# How can I store one to many in PostgreSQL via array of alt keys?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have two classes - Role and PosUser.

```cs
public class Role : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public string[] Permissions { get; set; }
    public bool IsProtected { get; set; }
    public uint Priority { get; set; }
    
    #region IEntity
    #endregion
}
```

```cs
public class PosUser : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    #region IEntity
    #endregion
}
```

**I want to have two tables on each of these entitites.**
Roles **should not know** anything about Users, but every User **should store** jsonb array of role's names like ["Admin", "Test"]

I tried to use:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Role>().HasAlternateKey(x => x.Name);

        builder.Entity<PosUser>().Property(u => u.Roles)
            .HasPostgresArrayConversion(r => r.Name, name => Find<Role>(name));
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

But I got error about context disposed.

**These doesn't fit:**

- Store links by ForeignKeys in new table
- Store all links to users at Role table

Comment: Why do you want to do this? That's not how you relate entities using postgres. JSONB is for storing fully non-relational data, not for relationships.

Comment: It can be just collection of strings. Main idea - to have User - Roles without additional tables, Main purpose - easy editable via db.

Comment: Easy editable via DB is a bad goal. Editing a production DB via direct DB access is a terrible security and catastrophic error risk and you should never do it.

Comment: I know it. But here's another purpose - all main info in one table, not at many tables.

I have this way in production in other project, works very well, but there's made by direct SQL queries, not ORM

Comment: That's also a bad thing. Relational databases are designed to have many tables. All this will do is lead to atrocious performance since you can't leverage joins. It's as if someone built a car with only one wheel because it was 'easier', and then the car could barely drive.

Comment: Still, I wonder if there is a solution to this problem provided in PostgreSQL, not why I should not use it. I know perfectly well that this is not recommended.

Comment: I'm not removing relational, I just want to build this relation in a different way

Comment: Here's description about that **antipattern**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729381/using-postgresql-array-to-store-many-to-many-relationship?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I'm glad you found someone else explaining in depth that you are wrong and should stop trying to do this.

Comment: Yes, I am the person who is looking for tough counterarguments, thx for discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new table to store a many:many relationship between `PosUser` and `Role`, let's call it `PosUserRoles`

```
public class PosUserRoles
{
    // FK to PosUser
    public string PosUserKey { get; set; }
    
    // FK to Role
    public string RoleKey { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's doesn't fit =(

Comment: @Greenorine, I'm not sure what you mean? If you don't want to use a relational database as a relational database, then I suppose you could store a `string` on `PosUser` and then in your `modelBuilder` you can call `builder.Entity<PosUser>().Property(x => x.RoleArray).HasColumnType("jsonb")`

Comment: I want relation, but a little bit another way, not via ID, but via Name property, and store list of these names in column Roles of PosUser table

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at https://www.relationaldbdesign.com/database-design/module6/three-relationship-types.php

Comment: We're saying that User has many roles in one hand, and in other hand - role should has user, but it's strange, that role should has it. The role is not positioned so that it has a user.

Comment: @Greenorine: This is not "role has a user".  That would be a "user id" column in the Roles table.  This answer is for a new table, which lists many (user, role) pairs.  That's how you build a many-to-many relationship in SQL.

Comment: Same thing, at example in the article you sent said: "An employee can work in many departments (>=0), and a department can have several employees". Users should have roles, but roles should not have users, that's what I mean

Comment: This is an additional expenditure on resources. Make a table of relationships instead of a list, that's represents relation compact way. Also if we want to delete some role, we need to delete link, more links - more dependence, instead of that I think better to edit entity or delete it with one sql instruction.

Comment: I think you solution is more effective if I want to list all users of some role

Comment: The solution is more effective under all circumstances, because relational databases are designed to optimize for this particular use case. The performance of a join is going to vastly outstrip whatever insane kludge you need to use to query on array elements. Plus, you can't enforce referential integrity with an array. Even if you never query in the reverse direction it's going to be vastly more performant. FOREIGN KEYS ARE HOW YOU MODEL RELATIONS IN SQL, DEAL WITH IT.

Comment: @NickBailey It's not more efficient, at least not in PostgreSQL and I doubt that it's in any other DBMS. Using arrays is much more space efficient, much faster to lookup user's roles (it's zero additional page loads) and bit faster to lookup role's users (only one index lookup, compared to 2).

That said, it probably won't matter on user's table, but in my DB it won't fit on my SSD if I "normalized" the schema.

Comment: *sigh*. In order to use arrays, you need to do a select on roles for each role a user has, because PG does not support array joins. That means instead of index scan once on users, once on userroles and once on roles, you have to do n index scans on roles, where n is the number of roles the user has. Unless you use an SP, that's also n extra network trips. There are cases where your approach might be more performant, for example if the number of roles is very small, the number of users huge, and each user has only a few roles.

Comment: Assume 1mil users, 5 roles per user avg, 100 roles. User lookup with join table is a 1mil row index lookup + 5mil row index lookup + 100 row index lookup, that's 20 index steps for the first lookup plus 23 for the join, plus plus fixed overhead for one select. Now the other way. You save one 23 step index lookup, and 5 row loads, in exchange for 5 more selects. Now how about backwards. With Join tables, its the same both ways, but with a bunch of extra row reads on users. With arrays, it is impossible without a GIN index, or a full table scan.

Comment: With a GIN index, the reverse lookup is very efficient. But... GIN indicies are huge, so you are going to be losing all of your purported space savings.

Comment: So TL;DR, you *might* get better performance with this technique depending on the shape of data, but it's far from a sure thing once you realize this fixed overhead of each query is high. Now, if you were to pull the set of roles into memory, and not try a clunky pseudo join at all, then you would have something effective.

Comment: Also, why are you worried about this fitting on an SSD? Real user role data shouldn't be on local anyway, since it's secure user data. If you can't fit this on a cloud hosted DB, then something is pathological.

Answer (score -1):

So the **final answer** is based on **Austin C** who decided basic **M:M** solution.

Code **example** based on question:

```cs
public class PosUser : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    #region IEntity
    #endregion
}

public class Role : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public string[] Permissions { get; set; }
    public bool IsProtected { get; set; }
    public uint Priority { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PosUser> Users { get; set; }

    #region IEntity
    #endregion
}
```

No need for anything else because EF Core can deal with models and it'll make links table like "PosUserRole".

What was tried is called "Jaywalking" and it's an anti-pattern ([Using PostgreSQL array to store many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729381/using-postgresql-array-to-store-many-to-many-relationship?rq=1))